# How to Raise DragDelta event on Thumb

Tags: wpf, events, wpf-controls, drag, raise

As you can see below, I want to start moving when the component visibility changes.
because otherwise I need the user to click again to start the movement, and that is bad in terms of usability for my application.

```
 public MoveILayoutControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.IsVisibleChanged += new DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler(MoveILayoutControl_IsVisibleChanged);
        this.moveThumb.DragDelta += new DragDeltaEventHandler(MoveThumb_DragDelta);
    }

    void MoveILayoutControl_IsVisibleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.IsVisible)
        {
            // Raise Drag Event !?
        }
    }

    private void MoveThumb_DragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        var myData = DataContext as ILayoutVisual;

        if (myData != null)
        {
            Point dragDelta = new Point(e.HorizontalChange, e.VerticalChange);

            if (myData.Rotation != 0)
            {
                Matrix toCalculate = ((this.Parent as FrameworkElement).RenderTransform).Value;
                if (toCalculate != null)
                {
                    dragDelta = toCalculate.Transform(dragDelta);
                }
            }
            myData.X += dragDelta.X;
            myData.Y += dragDelta.Y;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the only way is using reflection to change the internal values ​​of the thumb. Changing the property "IsDragging" (not tested).

Answer (score 0):

I looked up the [source code of `Thumb`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/Primitives/Thumb.cs,1625c1c79837b8ee) and I think a better way is to simulate a `MouseLeftButtonEvent` on the thumb:

```cs
var evt = new MouseButtonEventArgs(mouseDevice, timestamp, MouseButton.Left)
{
    RoutedEvent = UIElement.MouseLeftButtonDownEvent
};
thumb.RaiseEvent(evt);
```